# Не обновляется значение в random

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, случайные-числа, telegram, telebot

Я решил сделать команду которая будет временно блокировать пользователя, на рандомное время. Но время блокировки обновляется только после перезапуска приложения, а не после каждой новой блокировки.

```
 import telebot
 from time import time
 import random

 Time = [1920, 2760, 3480, 4440]
 ro_msg = ["32 минуты", "46 минут", "58 минут", "74 минуты"]

 X = random.randint(1, 4)

 strings = {
    "ro_win": "Вы выйграли РО на " + ro_msg[X]
    }


@bot.message_handler(commands=["win"])
def set_ro(message):
    bot.restrict_chat_member(message.chat.id, 
message.from_user.id, until_date=time()+Time[X])
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, strings.get("ro_win"),
                     reply_to_message_id=message.message_id)`
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас переменная Х - глобальная, и вычисляется один раз (при запуске скрипта), перенесите получение случайного числа `random.randint(1, 4)` внутрь `set_ro`, тогда оно будет вычисляться каждый раз заново (или `random.choice(Time)`)

Comment: Спасибо Большое!

Comment: @Анонимно если Вы получили исчерпывающий ответ и он Вас устраивает, то поставьте ему "зеленую галочку", что добавит рейтинга человеку, который Вам помог, а остальные увидят, что проблема решена.